# latest Changes are not reflecting in azure app service after deploying via azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have deployed java app in one of the app service using azuredevops pipeline.
I have tested in one environment where manual deployments are not done , it is working fine.
I have tested in another environment where manual deployments are done , here changes are not reflecting post deployment with azure devops pipeline
can anyone suggest